# How to view a single button I created under 'Component' in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a single button in a .ts file inside 'components' folder using react framework. I was wonder what is the quickest way to view the button I built.

As I am new, just to make sure it is not workable to use 'ts-node' to run right?

Comment: `ts-node` can be used as compiler(or transpiler), you can use it instead of '@bebel/preset-typescript' it's up to you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to React, I recommend using CRA first to view your custom component as fast as possible.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

```bash
$ npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
// or 
$ yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript // if you prefer yarn
```

The command above will do all the setup for you, you just need to go to the folder and run the app.

---

if you only want to do a custom React setup with TypeScript from scratch,

[Here's my post](https://dev.to/brandonwie/the-complete-guide-for-setting-up-react-app-from-scratch-feat-typescript-385b), using webpack, babel, and TypeScript